# Using npm to get AngularJS and include in Grunt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I'm new to grunt and want to build a script with concat and uglify. The script uses angularjs and therefore i need to include it.
I first did:

```
npm install angular
```

and this works, angular got installed to `node_modules/angular/angular.js`

My question is: What is best pratice to include it in the concatenated file?

Is it just:

```
concat: {
    seperator: ';',
    dist: {
            src: ['node_modules/angular/angular.js', 'src/js/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
    },
```

or is there a "better" way to include it in the output?

Regards,

F

Comment: What would you consider 'better'?

Comment: For example I could imagine using the package name as an include. Is anything like this possible or is it just the way it has to be done?

Comment: Nope that's not possible. How would bower know what npm has installed?